# How can I generate random data with Spark ?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

One row :

```
//Scala Code
val rndcolumn1 = randomInt(3,8)
val rndcolumn2 = randomInt(3,8)

val column1 = randomAlphaStr(rndcolumn1)
val column2 = randomAlphaStr(rndcolumn2)
//randomAlphaStr get random int and return random string. string.size range (3,8) ex : sfjhjk, ljl, rtddhjks  
val column3 = randomInt(11111111,99999999).toString 
val column4 = randomInt(11111,99999).toString

val str = column1 +"," +column2 + "," + column3 +  "," + column4 + "\n"
```

I want to generate big data. How can I generate this data and save on Hdfs with Spark ?

I want to see result :

```
output/
   ---part-00000
   ---part-00001
    ....
```